# use c Token-Pasting to access field in struct

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to use c token pasting (##) to access to struct field as below:

```
typedef struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
} TMP_T;

#define BUILD_FIELD(field) my_struct.##field

int main()
{
     TMP_T my_struct;
     BUILD_FIELD(a) = 5;
     return 0;
}
```

But got the following error during compilation:
error: pasting "." and "a" does not give a valid preprocessing token

I would like to add additional case to that:

```
 typedef struct {
 int a;
 int b;
 }TMP_T;

 #define BUILD_FIELD(my_struct,field) my_struct.##field


  void func(char* name)
  {
TMP_T tmp_str;
if((name == "a")  || (name == "b"))
{
    BUILD_FIELD(tmp_str, name) = 7;
    printf("%d \n", BUILD_FIELD(a) );
}


 }

 int main()
 {

       func("a");
       return 1;
 }
```

How should I use the macro to access the specific struct and field. Is it  possible? or because its a pre compiled then it couldn't be defined for various fields (a,b)

Thanks
Moti

Comment: This is totally wrong. You can't mix macros with runtime stuff. Macro processing ends after preprocessing, even before compilation. Perhaps you need a scripting language. Lastly, you can't compare strings with `==`.

Comment: address your last edit in my answer below.  Agree with both of @perreal's observations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need token pasting at all:

```
#define BUILD_FIELD(field) my_struct.field
```

According to the [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) token pasting should result in an identifier or a number after the concatenation. The error is due to the `.a` not being either.

Comment: Thanks for getting me straitened out on `##`.  I had never used it before, but most likely will now.

Comment: Thanks,Actually, I didn't asked the rigth question. I'm getting the field as a pointer to function like follow:     typedef struct {
     int a;
     int b;
     }TMP_T;

#define BUILD_FIELD(my_struct,field) my_struct.##field


void func(char* name)
{
 TMP_T tmp_str;
 if((name == "a")  || (name == "b"))
 {
  BUILD_FIELD(tmp_str, name) = 7;
  printf("%d \n", BUILD_FIELD(a) );
 }
 

}

int main()
{

func("a");
return 1;
}

Comment: I am now curious.  I ran my code as it is shown in my answer, except with `##` just as OP did.  It caused ***no error***.  And according to what I read in the ***[link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)***, it shouldn't have.  So, can you elaborate on what you stated as being the cause of OP error?  ( _The error is due to the .a not being either._ )

Comment: @ryyker, look at the link in the answer, it explains clearly. After pasting, gcc expects to have an identifier or a number. You are compiling with MS compiler so it may behave differently. In any case, pasting is not necessary.

Comment: @moti - Can you please put all that into your original post, with some formatting so it is easier to read, and can be address more clearly?

Comment: @perreal - I am actually compiling with a non-Microsoft, ANSI C99 compiler.  But I will take this on as a learning project and do some reading, and experimenting on my own.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All that is required is to use the macro replacement string `field`.  Try this:

`#define BUILD_FIELD(field) my_struct.field`.

So the following code will work:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

typedef struct  {
    int a;
    int b;
}TMP_T;

#define BUILD_FIELD(field) my_struct.field

int main(void)
{
     TMP_T my_struct;
     BUILD_FIELD(a) = 5;
     printf("my_struct.a is %d\n",my_struct.a); 
     BUILD_FIELD(b) = 10;
     printf("my_struct.b is %d\n",my_struct.b); 
     return 0;
}
```

***By the way***, I also ran the above code with the line:  (after having read  ***[Krister Andersson's link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)***)

```
#define BUILD_FIELD(field) my_struct.##field
```

It ran identical to the code without using `##` stringification.  So, there is obviously something different between our compilers.
***In any case***, I hope my original assertions did not add too much confusion.  Your question taught me a few lessons today.  Thanks! (+1)

***Addressing your latest post edit:***

First of all this modification will result in a compile error for an unknown field name within TMP_T here:

```
BUILD_FIELD(tmp_str, name) = 7;
```

Here is a ***[good link](http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/c/PreprocessCompileLink.htm)*** that discusses Preprocessing, Compiling and Linking (of greatest interest for this discussion will be the preprocessing and compile parts).   Among other things, it discusses when to use macros.

Also, regarding the line:

```
if((name == "a")  || (name == "b"))
```

When doing string compares, the `==` is not used.  `strcmp()`, or even `strstr()` are used for string comparisons.

Comment: Down-voter.  At least say why you are down-voting.  I will address the problem if there is one.

Comment: `##` is very much legal in C. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html.

Comment: @perreal - I stand corrected. (and learned something I did not know)   I will modify my post.  Thank you.

Comment: @KristerAndersson - I really did not know that.  Have modified my post.  Thank you for that link :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need pasting if you create your struct with some "structure". For example:

```
 typedef struct
 {
    int tmp_a;
    int tmp_b;
 } TMP_T;

 #define BUILD_FIELD(field) my_struct.tmp_##field
```

It's used for tokenization. Your use case is the "typical" macro variable replacement.